# jQuery slide in and out issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://nuskora.com/staging/) is my URL site.

Here you can see a search bar on the top right corner. If you click on the search icon it will show you a search box. Now again, If you click on the search icon again then it's should close the search box like sliding effect but it's not working.

**JQuery code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#search2').on("click",(function(e){
    jQuery(".form-group").addClass("sb-search-open");
      e.stopPropagation()
    }));
    jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if (jQuery(e.target).is("#search2") === false && jQuery(".form-control").val().length == 0) {
        jQuery(".form-group").removeClass("sb-search-open");
      }
    });
    jQuery(".form-control-submit").click(function(e){
      jQuery(".form-control").each(function(){
      if(jQuery(".form-control").val().length == 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "addClass" in third line to "toggleClass":

```
    jQuery(".form-group").toggleClass("sb-search-open");
```

Comment: Hi, Having issue. After click on the search icon. it's showing the text box but I can't write anything because it's hiding immediately.

Comment: Hi. Instead of binding the click event to the search input using the "#search2" selector, you can bind it to the icon class ".search-label". Just switch them and it should work as you want

Comment: let me try with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, looks like you are closing the search bar when clicking anywhere else except the search icon itself

```
jQuery(e.target).is("#search2") === false
```

And it works as expected, if you want it to behave otherwise then replace false with true.

Comment: Well, let me try with this.

Comment: Now, its not doing anything after make it true :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#search2').on("click",(function(e){
    jQuery("#search").toggleClass("sb-search-open");
      e.stopPropagation()
    }));

});
```